# Compass: How to reference to different sprites with identical folder names?

Tags: directory, sprite, conflict, compass-sass

Suppose we have 2 sprite folders inside the `img` folder of a standard Compass project. Inside each one of them, we have other 2 folders with identical names:

```
project/img/chapter1/icons
project/img/chapter2/icons
```

We know Compass uses the last folder name so as to reference to the sprite. But, in this case, how could one call each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the magic, use the helpers:

```
$icons1-sprite: sprite-map("project/img/chapter1/icons/*.png");
$icons2-sprite: sprite-map("project/img/chapter2/icons/*.png");
```

See here for more: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/