# Sprite theming with Compass/SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have two themes, each with its own icons in a spritesheet. My problem is: how can I select, using a class name of a container, which spritesheet to use if they are named the same way?

This is a problem with wanting to have two image collections use the same name.

```
@import "style-skin-default/icon/*.png";
/* @import "style-skin-dark/icon/*.png"; --- can't do this, both imports will be names "icon" */
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@include all-icon-sprites;
```

This creates classes like `.icon-back`, `.icon-check`, `.icon-close` and so on.

I want to use themes with HTML like this:

```
<div class="widget widget-theme-default">
  <div class="icon-close"></div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget-theme-dark">
  <div class="icon-close"></div>
</div>
```

Using SASS in the lines of:

```
.widget.widget-theme-default {
    @include all-icon-sprites; /* include default sprites */
}
.widget.widget-theme-default {
    @include all-icon-sprites; /* include dark sprites --- what syntax to use here? */
}
```

I want to get resulting CSS like:

```
.widget.widget-theme-default .icon-back,
.widget.widget-theme-default .icon-next,
.widget.widget-theme-default .icon-... {
  background: ...spritesheet default...
}
.widget.widget-theme-default .icon-back { background-position: ... }
.widget.widget-theme-default .icon-next { background-position: ... }
.widget.widget-theme-default .icon-...  { background-position: ... }

.widget.widget-theme-dark.icon-back,
.widget.widget-theme-dark.icon-next,
.widget.widget-theme-dark.icon-... {
  background: ...spritesheet dark...
}
.widget.widget-theme-dark.icon-back { background-position: ... }
.widget.widget-theme-dark.icon-next { background-position: ... }
.widget.widget-theme-dark.icon-...  { background-position: ... }
```

---

What I **don't** want to do:

- hack the sprite system and reuse generated sprite files
- import two spritesheets under different names so I have to change the HTML to add every possible combination ie. `<div class="darkicon-close defaulticon-close"></div>`
- manually import mix-ins of every sprite to my custom class; there are too many of them

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727643/compass-how-to-reference-to-diferent-sprites-with-identical-folder-names